# Get data from json file if value of a key matches that of a stored variable

Tags: javascript, json

I want to be able to fetch data from a JSON file only if a value of a key matches that of an already stored variable in my script. For example, I have two stored variables:

- Weather, which has a value of hot.
- Distance, which has a value of 4.

I want to return only the objects in the JSON file that have these key value pairs and save the objects into an array. Any help would be much appreciated.

Heres my json file called 'locations.json':

```json
[
  {
    "Distance ": 2,
    "Weather": "cold"
  },
  {
    "Distance ": 4,
    "Weather": "hot"
  },
  {
    "Distance ": 3,
    "Weather": "cold"
  },
  {
    "Distance ": 4,
    "Weather": "hot"
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use `array#find` for this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+filter+object+array+more+than+one+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @HassanImam that will only find ONE object. They need [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Be careful, you have a space in the Distance key. The code could be this: `const dist = 4, wthr = "hot";
const arr = data.filter(({Distance,Weather}) => Distance === dist && Weather === wthr);`

Comment: Thanks. In order to get the data, do I use fetch()?